# Zip different directories in hadoop using bash script

Tags: bash, hadoop, zip, hdfs

I have a location in hadoop , which is having different directories in it like dir1 dir2 etc. I need to zip those different directories as different zip files .

I have used the following script, but that is not working .

```
for d in ${directory_to_move_files}/*/ ;

do
    echo "$d" ;
//zip the folders printed in echo

done
```

Can somebody point out the right way of doing it .

Comment: its not related to hadoop(could you delete hadoop tag). Its simple shell script. pls. see my answer :)

Comment: I need to use the shell in hadoop  , that is why added .

Comment: ok. But are you copying the hadoop folder using hadoop fs -coptolocal in that case ?

Comment: I am looking through the answers .. Actually the location is in hadoop and I need to zip all the directories in that location like /abc/def/pqr/
I need to zip different directories in that location like dir1 , dir2

Comment: So this zipping will not work in hadoop environment ?

Comment: What I doubted was correct!  thats why you added hadoop tag as I understood.   I  cant see anything here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112410/discussion-between-ramprasad-g-and-dileepvikram).

Comment: updated answer please check that!

Comment: any findings apart from my answer?

Comment: @RamPrasadG  As you mentioned I have decided to move the files to local and proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is go to parent directory to local linux folder with hadoop fs -copyToLocal   where you want to execute and do the below by saving in shell script
   look at `FileSystem` command [reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
for eachindex in */; do zip -r "${eachindex%/}.zip" "$eachindex"; done
```

As I understood that, your question has deep insight(not just unix bash command and shell scripts) and  you want to do zip with in hadoop environment only and not by copying it to local unix/linux file system.

I did research on this and only way I found is using [**FUSE aka  (Filesystem in Userspace**) interface into HDFS](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_hdfs_mountable.html)
also see [**MountableHDFS**](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS)

I don't know how far its feasible for you. In our implementation, I have done through copying hdfs file to local file system and executed shell scripts.

Comment: I have used a cd to the location of the directories to be zipped , as otherwise the zip command will unzip the unwanted directories

Comment: if you are okay with answer can you please vote it up as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
find ${directory_to_move_files}/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;
```